# how to iterate a vector containing references?

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```
fn find_rects<'a >(
      rects: & Vec<&'a Rectangle>,  // reference of a vec containing Rectangle references
      width_limit: u32)
      ->  Vec<&'a Rectangle> // returns a vec of Rectangle references
{
    rects
        .iter()
        .filter(|x| x.width > width_limit)
        .collect()
}
```

It failed to compile. The error message says:

```
.collect()
 ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<&Rectangle>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&&Rectangle>`
```

And I found an answer to use `.copied().collect()` instead of `.collect()`. I tested and it works.
But I don't know the reason.

Comment: [Copied ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) _This is useful when you have an iterator over `&T`, but you need an iterator over `T`._ This is the case that your error points.

Comment: `.iter()` makes an iterator over `&T` from a `&Vec<T>`, so you end up with `&&Rectangle`s. `.copied()` derefs and copies each element to give you `&Rectangle`s again.

Comment: (Off-topic): [you should take `&[&'a Rectangle]` as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/8376184)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `my_vec: Vec<T>`, then `my_vec.iter()` is an iterator over `&T`. But in this case `T` is `&Rectangle` so the iterator is over `&&Rectangle`, which is a distinct type from `&Rectangle` and so cannot be `collect`ed into a `Vec<&Rectangle>`.

`iterator.copied()` takes an iterator over `&U` and produces an iterator over `U` by copying (in the sense of `Copy`) each element (by dereferencing it; `copied()` is equivalent to `iterator.map(|&x| x)` and `iterator.map(|x| *x)`).

All that's left is to recognize that `U` is `&Rectangle` and that `&U: Copy` for any `U`, including when `U` is `&Rectangle`. So `Iterator<Item=&&Rectangle>::copied()` produces an iterator of `&Rectangle`, which can indeed be `collect`ed into a `Vec<&Rectangle>` (or, really, any `FromIterator`, of which `Vec` is just one).